# Session state variable not working betweek these pages C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, typed-dataset

I am retrieving values from database, i checked the values are coming fine but when i try to run the code and it transfer me from LOGIN page to the MOVIE PLAYER form the session value is not working?

THIS IS MY LOGIN PAGE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PlayMovie
{
    public partial class LoginForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private LoginBLL bll;

    public LoginForm()
    {
        bll = new LoginBLL();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string uname = txtBoxUsername.Text.Trim();
        string pass = txtBoxPass.Text.Trim();

        LoginBLL customer = bll.GetName(uname);

        bool entry = bll.CheckLoginCreds(pass, uname);
        if (entry)
        {
            Response.Redirect("MoviePlayer.aspx");
            /*Session["FirstName"] = 
            Session["LastName"] = customer.LName;*/

            Session["fName"] = customer.FName;


        }
        else {
            lblInvalidLogin.Text = "Login Failed";
            lblInvalidLogin.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }

    protected void linkBtnReg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server.Transfer("Register.aspx", true);
    }
}
}
```

Now this is my MOVIEPLAYER

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PlayMovie
{
    public partial class PlayMovie : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private MovieBLL bll;

    public PlayMovie() {
        bll = new MovieBLL();
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadListBoxData();

            string sessionValue = (string)Session["fName"];
            labelFName.Text = sessionValue;
            //Response.Write(firstName);
        }

    }

    public void LoadListBoxData() {
        List<MovieBLL> listMovies = bll.LoadMovieNames();
        listBoxMovies.DataSource = listMovies;
        listBoxMovies.DataTextField = "MovieName";
        listBoxMovies.DataValueField = "MovieID";
        listBoxMovies.DataBind();
    }
    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void FillMovieData()
    {
        foreach (ListItem movie in listBoxMovies.Items)
        {

          if (movie.Selected)
            {
                int movieID = Convert.ToInt32(movie.Value);
                string movieName = movie.Text;

                MovieBLL movieData = bll.GetMovieData(movieID);
                if (movieData != null)
                {
                    txtBoxMName.Text =movie.Text;
                    txtBoxMGenre.Text = movieData.MovieGenre;
                    txtBoxMRating.Text = movieData.MovieRating+"/5.0";
                    txtBoxMDesc.Text = movieData.MovieDesc;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtBoxMName.Text = "";
                    txtBoxMGenre.Text = "";
                    txtBoxMRating.Text = "";
                    txtBoxMDesc.Text = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected void listBoxMovies_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //FillMovieData();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillMovieData();
        moviePlayer.Enabled = true;
        btnPlay.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem movie in listBoxMovies.Items)
        {

            if (movie.Selected)
            {
                moviePlayer.FullScreen = true;
                moviePlayer.MovieURL = @"\Movies\" + movie.Text + ".mp4";
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

We can clearly see that i retreived value from database i.e. customer.FName and then put it into a session variable, then i used response.redirect to go to other page and then i retreived my session variable and put it into a label but it is showing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @Buttman on your login page you need to set the session variable before you redirect the user (otherwise the session value is never set, and will not be accessible - as you are currently seeing).

To fix this try re-ordering your login page code to:

```
    Session["fName"] = customer.FName;       // Set Session first
    Response.Redirect("MoviePlayer.aspx");   // Then redirect user.
```

That should then allow you to access the session variable in subsequent pages. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you sir, that helped!! i was dumb!!

Comment: can you help me in one more thing, in the same application i am trying to upload a file around 1gb but it wont let me do that, I have tried editing my web.config but the solutions available just dont work!! is there a workaround